# LDAP Access - javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed

Tags: java, ldap, ssl-certificate, keystore

We are running into issues connecting LDAP server after LDAP SHA-256 Migration .We got the below exception when we ran our application in debug mode :

```
  javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: xxxamd.xxx.com:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed]​
```

We tried to add the below .cer files into our application specific cacerts file:

1. GlobalSignRootCA.cer
2. GlobalSignOrganizationValidationCA-G2.cer
3. OrganizationValidationCA-SHA256-G2.cer

After adding the above .cer file in cacerts ,we are getting different exception :

```
getLdapContactInfo(): javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: xxxamd.xxx.com:636 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: Certificate signature validation failed]
```

**Server :**

> Perl Web Farm Server

**Java Version :**

```
xxxxx@yyyy:~/www $ java -version

java version "1.4.2_19"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.4.2_19-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.4.2_19-b04, mixed mode)
```

Any help or suggestion on this regard is greatly appreciated.

Note: SUN JRE has been implemented in Server level and our application is IBM JRE under the `/cgi-bin/` folder. We tried adding certificate(mentioned above) in "cacerts" under `/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/security/` but nothing worked.

​

Comment: My gut felling is that is has something to do with verifying the certificate issuing authority. Especially if your LDAP can't reach the Internet. In that case you'd have to locally install certificates all the way up the certification tree. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_certificate

Comment: Thanks Defectus. I resolved the issue. The issue is with the Java Version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted out why am getting the above exception. The above 3 .cer files are not compatible to `Java 1.4.2`. So i tried pointing my application  to **`Java 1.6`** and the issue got resolved. Am able to retrieve information from the LDAP server.

Thanks